# How to sort array of object on the basis of Props

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

What is the best way to sort any array of object on the basis of property.

input:

```
[
{value: true, name: 'a'},
{value: false, name: 'c'},
{value: true, name: 'b'},
{value: false, name: 'd'},
{value: true, name: 'f'},
{value: true, name: 'e'}
]
```

output:

```
[
{value: true, name: 'a'},
{value: true, name: 'b'},
{value: true, name: 'f'},
{value: true, name: 'e'},
{value: false, name: 'c'},
{value: false, name: 'd'}
]
```

Comment: Seems to be plenty of popular answers on SO:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/979256/sorting-an-array-of-objects-by-property-values?rq=1

Comment: Not downvoting, but invest some time in searching before asking a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const source = [
  { value: true,  name: 'a' },
  { value: false, name: 'c' },
  { value: true,  name: 'b' },
  { value: false, name: 'd' },
  { value: true,  name: 'f' },
  { value: true,  name: 'e' }
];

console.log(source.sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value));
```